# Model for fibers optics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, fiber-optics

> A circular glass cylinder is a simplified model for fiber optics. Calculate the maximum incidence angle $\theta$ at the entrance face at which the light will be guided into the fiber by successive total reflections as a function of the refractive index $n$ of the fiber.
>
> [image]

It's been a short time since I started studying optics. I found this question in a book and I dont know how to start this question. Can someone help me? I don't need a complete solution, only one way would already be very good.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to calculate the maximum incidence angle for total internal reflection (for larger angles, the refracted ray will leak out of the fiber). Since angle of incidence equals angle of reflection, if the ray undergoes total internal reflection once, it should continue to do so on its subsequent reflections.

Comment: Sorry, I just do not understand how to use the last part. I'm having a bit of trouble finding an equation for this.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)#Laws_of_reflection